# How to create a nested array of object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

How Can I loop through this array of objects and change it so that the individual menu items are nested in the object menu_name?

```
const menus = [
  { menu_name: 'Entre', id:0 },
  {
    name: 'Soup',
    price: 14.99,
    id:1
  },
  {
    name: 'Chips & Salsa',
    price: 7.99,
    id:2
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken Nuggets',
    price: 12.99,
    id:3
  },
  { menu_name: 'Sides', id:4 },
  {
    name: 'Fries',
    price: 4.99,
    id:5
  },
  {
    name: 'Drinks',
    price: 2.99,
    id:6
  },
  {
    name: 'Onion Rings',
    price: 5.99,
    id:7
  },
];
```

the end result should look like this for each menu_name object, where an array of menus is nested in the menu_name object

```
  {
        menu_name: 'Sides',
        menu: [
          {
            name: 'Fries',
            price: 4.99,
          },
          {
            name: 'Drinks',
            price: 2.99,
          },
          {
            name: 'Onion Rings',
            price: 5.99,
          },
        ],
      },
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const menus = [
  { menu_name: "Entre", id: 0 },
  {
    name: "Soup",
    price: 14.99,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Chips & Salsa",
    price: 7.99,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "Chicken Nuggets",
    price: 12.99,
    id: 3,
  },
  { menu_name: "Sides", id: 4 },
  {
    name: "Fries",
    price: 4.99,
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "Drinks",
    price: 2.99,
    id: 6,
  },
  {
    name: "Onion Rings",
    price: 5.99,
    id: 7,
  },
];

const result = menus.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { menu_name } = curr;
  if (menu_name) {
    acc.push({ menu_name, menu: [] });
  } else {
    const { name, price } = curr;
    acc[acc.length - 1].menu.push({ name, price });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Will you please explain how,
acc[acc.length - 1].menu.push({ name, price }); // how this line is working?
Why not acc.menu.push({ name, price }); // not working?

Comment: @MamunurRashid `acc.menu.push({ name, price });` means `acc` is an `object` and `menu` is an `array` in which you are pushing an object which contains `name` and `price`. But what I've made structure is an array of objects. Since it an array so you need to find the object in which `menu` property exist and then push the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newMenu = [];
menus.forEach(menu=>{
  if(menu.menu_name){
      newMenu.push({...menu, menu: []})
  }else{
      newMenu[newMenu.length-1].menu.push(menu)
  }
});
```